# toLowerCase() function does not play nicely with passport.js authenticate

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am working on the "register" route for my web application. In my route, I convert the username that the user enters to lowercase using the toLowerCase() function, but that causes the passport.authenticate() method to fail (the user still get registered perfectly fine) and redirects to Unauthorized (401) response. When I tried without using the toLowerCase() function, it works just fine. Not sure what I am missing here so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
router.post("/register", isLoggedOut, function(req,res){
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;
var confirm_password = req.body.confirm_password;
for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++){
    if (username.toLowerCase() == emails[i].toLowerCase()){
        username = username.toLowerCase(); 
        if (password != confirm_password){
            req.flash("error", "Passwords do not match!");
            return res.redirect("/register");
        } else {
            console.log("Password matches! Signing up now");
            console.log("Type of username is " + typeof req.body.username);
            console.log("Type of username after lowercase: " + typeof req.body.username.toLowerCase());
            var newUser = new User({username: username, role: "public"});
            User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
                if (err){
                    console.log("There is an error in registration: " + err);
                    req.flash("error", err.message);
                    return res.redirect("/register");
                }
                passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(err){
                    if (err){
                        console.log("ERROR IN AUTHENTICATE!: " + err);
                    }
                    req.flash("success", "Welcome");
                    return res.redirect("/blogs");
                });
            });
        }
    }
    else {
        if (i == emails.length - 1){
            console.log("Email is not in system");
            req.flash("error", "Your email is not in our system!");
            return res.redirect("/register");
        } 
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Why would you convert it to lowercase? Seems like you're using emails as usernames, what if you ever wanted to send an email or show the username to the user, it won't match what the user typed in? Generally you should just validate user input like that, not change it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes. they are being used as username. When I send an email to the user, it does not matter if it is lowercase or upppercase, the email will go through so I am not concerned about that. I want all username to be lowercase for consistency and generally, I just want to know why the toLowerCase() function would cause that error